# add item in array which loops in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I have a `foreach` loop which loops though an array of items. The `checkIfSubCategorie()` returns an array with new items.

I want to place all these items in the `$subcategorien` array. This works good. The problem is that those items don't go through the initial foreach loop. Is this possible and if yes, how?

```
foreach($subcategorien as $subcat) {

    //make array with all subcategorien
    $newarray = self::checkIfSubCategorie($subcat);

    if(is_array($newarray)) {
        foreach($newarray as $a) {

            // add item to subcategorien
            array_push($subcategorien, $a);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `$subcategorien` array **before** the initial `foreach` loop:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(3) "701"
  [1]=> string(3) "702"
}
```

var_dump of `$newarray`:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(1) "8"
}
bool(false)
```

This is the `$subcategorien` array **after** the `foreach` loop:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(3) "701"
  [1]=> string(3) "702"
  [2]=> string(1) "8"
}
```

The result should be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(3) "701"
  [1]=> string(3) "702"
  [2]=> string(1) "8"
  [3]=> string(1) "9"
}
```

Comment: can you var_dump the value of $newarray in the first loop, before line4?

Comment: Hi, Can you please show your array's output

Comment: So, just to be sure I understand, you want the new values added to $subcategorien to be lopped in the first foreach?

Comment: @Epodax yes that's what I want

Comment: @rahul added the output

Comment: can you please elaborate your array of $subcategorien and what output you want so i can make example and try it

Comment: @rahul It's to check if a certain category has any subcategory. The numbers are the id's of the category's Let's say I start with category "7", "701" and "702" are subcategory's of 7. If  "701" or "702" have any subcategory's I want them to be added to the array. In this case "8" is a subcategory of "701"

Comment: show us a expected output array

Comment: var_dump the $subcategorien and post the result

Comment: then that means that $newarray is not a array on the 2nd loop

Comment: @RobertVerkerk your code seems perfect to me, and i have checked in my local, it may be issue with your checkIfSubCategorie function not returning the array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `recursive function`. Something like:

```
function getCategoryChildren($categoryParentId, $categories = array()) {
    // TODO: query to get all the categories by their parents id
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
         $categories[] = $row['category_id'];
         $categories = getCategoryChildren($row['category_id'], $categories);
    }
    return $categories;
}

$allCategories = getCategoryChildren(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP Manuals `array_push()` will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array. This differs from the `$var[]` behavior where a new array is created.

If you use `array_push()` to add one element to the array it's better to use `$array[] =` because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it similar to your code:

```
 $result_array = array();
 foreach($subcategorien as $subcat){
    //make array with all subcategorien
    $newarray = checkIfSubCategorie($subcat);
    $result_array[] = $subcat;
    if(is_array($newarray)){
        foreach($newarray as $a){
         $result_array[] = $a;
        }
    }
 }
```